# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /audio

Tags: javascript, html, django, audio, mp3

i have website with button to upload audio mp3 on a post. the problem, when i clicked the button, it's open new / (http://localhost:8000/audio) actually just http://localhost:8000. and when i see terimal, there's error message

> Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /audio

at the same time, there's error at my website with error message

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> Help Reason given for failure:
>
> CSRF token missing or incorrect.
> In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used
> correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
>
> Your browser is accepting cookies. The view function passes a request
> to the template's render method. In the template, there is a {%
> csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an
> internal URL. If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must
> use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as
> well as those that accept the POST data. The form has a valid CSRF
> token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back
> button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form,
> because the token is rotated after a login. You're seeing the help
> section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
> settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error
> message will be displayed.
>
> You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.

what i want is, i can upload file song mp3 with django without database (just local). and the song can be defined by information such as artist, duration, genre, etc.

and here's my code:

```
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^decode/$', views.decode),
    url(r'^$', views.homepage),
    path('audio', views.Audio_store),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from subprocess import call
from django.core.files import File
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import subprocess
from MusicLockApp.forms import AudioForm

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def homepage(request):
    # return HttpResponse('homepage')
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')

def decode(request):
    # return HttpResponse('about')
    return render(request, 'decode.html')

    #@csrf_exempt
def obfuscate(request):
    print("HI")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse("Hi")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("files: " + str(request.FILES))
        print("posts: " + str(request.POST))

        if len(request.POST) > 0:
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['audio_file'])

    return HttpResponse("The form was valid!")

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('temp.mp3', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

    subprocess.check_call("ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp3 temp.wav", shell=True)

def Audio_store(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('SUKSES BRUH')
    else:
        form = AudioForm()
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'form' : form})
```

models.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models

class Audio_store(models.Model):
    record=models.FileField(upload_to='media/mp3')
    class Meta:
        db_table='Audio_store'
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from MusicLockApp.models import *

class AudioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Audio_store
        fields=['record']
```

add settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/mp3/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mp3')
```

homepage.html script:

```
<script>
        var file = undefined;
        var audio_formats = ["mp3"];
        
        // using jQuery
        function getCookie(name) {
          var cookieValue = null;
        
          if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        
          return cookieValue;
        }
        
        function fileAdded() {
          var x = document.getElementById("audio-file");
          file = x.files[0];
          var msg = document.getElementById("message");
        
          if (file != undefined) {
            x = file.name.split(".");
            var ext = x[x.length - 1];
        
            if (audio_formats.indexOf(ext) == -1) {
              msg.innerHTML = ext + " is not an audio file!";
            } else {
              msg.innerHTML = file.name + " has been successfully added!";
            }
          } else {
            msg.innerHTML = "Please select an audio file to obfuscate!";
          }
        }
        
        function obfuscate() {
          if (file == undefined)
            alert("Choose an audio file!");
          else {
            var obfuscateButton = document.getElementById("obfuscate-button");
            obfuscateButton.innerHTML = "Proccessing...";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/obfuscator/obfuscate/";
            var method = 'POST';
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                  obfuscateButton.innerHTML = "Done!"
              }
            }
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("audio_file", file);
            formData.append("file_name", file.name)
            xhr.send(formData);
          }
        }
        </script>
```

```css
.dsnupload {
    background-color: #fbc786;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
}

.dsnupload:hover {
    background-color: #c88f5c;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                            <form action="audio" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %^}
                            {{ form }}
                            <button type="submit" class="dsnupload" id="audio-file" onchange="fileAdded()">
                                <i class="large material-icons" style="font-size: 50pt; margin-top: 10px;">audiotrack</i>
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Insert file audio (mp3)</p>
                            </button>
                            <p id="message"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Did you check if you are getting the cookie ? you can pass the the following method to a variable let test =  getCookie('csrftoken'), then console.log(test) before         xhr.send(formData); line. Also check if you included session middleware in settings.py. One final note, sessions is managed in Django, so when you hit submit button in the template it should send csrf token to the backend , no need to manage csrf in JS.

Comment: where i should give test = getCookie('csrftoken')? i was update my add settings.py. ooh okay, i will delete all my JS! @araldhafeeri

Comment: i was give test but it doesn't show anything @araldhafeeri

Comment: then the token has not been set